# $.parseJSON() returns null on valid object

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/YmUmp/1/)

```
var x = {
    "Item1" : 1,
    "Item2" : {
        "Item3" : 3
    }
}

   alert(JSON.stringify(x, undefined, 2));
   alert($.parseJSON(x));
```

First one alerts valid object. The second one alerts null. In the real code, the "x" variable can be string or an object, so I should be able to parse both types. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes: the word "parse" is about interpreting strings, not already-constructed objects.  It doesn't make sense to talk about parsing an object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're parsing an object. You parse strings, not objects; [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) only takes strings. From the documentation:

> jQuery.parseJSON( json )
>
> json
>
> The JSON string to parse.

Usage:

```
if (! window.console) {
    console = {
        log: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    };
}

console.log($.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(x, undefined, 2)));
```

Standard jQuery doesn't appear to have a JSON stringifier. Typically, jQuery handles that for you, so it isn't necessary. If you need it, there are various plugins.

Comment: I thought it accepts objects too and just returns it back... was wrong. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Thanks ! I was looking for this solution from a long time !!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var x = { "Item1" : 1, "Item2" : { "Item3" : 3 }};
var stringified = JSON.stringify(x, undefined, 2);
var objectified = $.parseJSON(stringified);

alert(stringified);
alert(objectified.Item1);
alert(JSON.stringify(objectified, undefined, 2););
```

As mentioned above, this will give the parser a string to parse into an object, not the object itself.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uaN8G/

Comment: I was actually using this method, but I just hate to write an object as a string... I sometimes use toString(), but it's not the best way to go. Thanks for the answer though! +1

Comment: Hah! I forgot to update my code sample... I wasn't supposed to have the quoted string, but be the actual object. Check out the updated fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/wHWeJ/