# Why can I not parse json string using jQuery.parseJSON(json)?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I am trying to parse a response of a string which is a json string. In another page of my web app following code is working fine. but its not working for my current page i am working with. Following is the code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mywebapp.com/sendnames',
    data: {},
    success: function(result) {
        alert('result: '+result);
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        alert('obj: '+obj);

    // doing rest of stuff  
    }

});
```

first alert comes and shows right result. result is:

```
 [
   "Richard",
   "Eric",
   "John"
 ]
```

but second alert does not come.
i checked it, its a valid json. why can not i parse this json with jQuery.parseJSON(). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `alert('obj: '+obj);` show `Richard,Eric,John`?

Comment: It's probably because jQuery has already checked the type and your result is a JSON object already. Try alerting the typeof result and seeing what you get. Or accessing one of the expected properties.

Comment: @Musa no that alert does not come. thats why i wrote jQuery.parseJSON is not working.

Comment: i am getting the response i want. i debug jquery using alerts. did not get which console are you talking about?

Comment: I agree with Alex and do a console.log  instead of alert. Console.log(result).Let us know the result

Comment: If the `parseJSON` has worked then it will create a javascript object from the result into obj. Generally you can't alert an object and expect to get it's structure, instead you will get something like  `element object` back. If you are using firefox try `alert("obj: " + obj.toSource());`

Comment: in console i am getting this error: --
[10:50:59.362] TypeError: jQuery.parseJSON is not a function

Comment: JSON.parse is working but i still do not understand that why jQuery.parseJSON is not working. I have jQuery.parseJSON working in my another page. but not on this particular page

Answer (score 2):

Try to add return type: dataType : json

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://mywebapp.com/sendnames',
        data: {},
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(result) {
          console.log('result: '+result);        
        // doing rest of stuff  
        }

    });
```

**"json":** 
Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)
"jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: jQuery.parseJSON is still wrong, because dataType:json will cause jQuery do that internally. The result variable will already contain a JS object.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$.ajax` by `$.getJSON`. This is guaranteed to trigger `$.parseJSON` internally, so `result` will already be the desired JS object.

```
$.getJSON({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://mywebapp.com/sendnames',
   data: {},
   success: function(obj) {
      alert('obj: '+obj);
      // doing rest of stuff  
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding `dataType:'text'`, it will return string as result. and your code will run as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

[See the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631977/parsejson-returns-null-on-valid-object)

> You're parsing an object. You parse strings, not objects;
>   jQuery.parseJSON only takes strings.

Because `$.ajax` already parsed the data, `result` is Javascript object not a string. `parseJSON` expects a string parameter.

FROM [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (more on [`.ajax()` data types here](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests)):

> The json type parses the fetched data file as a JavaScript object and
>   returns the constructed object as the result data. To do so, it uses
>   jQuery.parseJSON() when the browser supports it; otherwise it uses a
>   Function constructor

.

Comment: in your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631977/parsejson-returns-null-on-valid-object the json object was declared and intialized client-side here the case is not the same i.e. here the resultant object is from external ajax calls which can be `anything` !!

Comment: I'm guessing `http://mywebapp.com/sendnames` returns the mime type as JSON, and therefore JQuery.parseJSON() is run on the data automatically by jquery.